# Get filename on server while using Ruby gem Curb

Tags: ruby, curb

Is there a way to get the filename of the file being downloaded (without having to parse the url provided)? I am hoping to find something like:

```
c = Curl::Easy.new("http://google.com/robots.txt")
c.perform
File.open( c.file_name, "w") { |file| file.write c.body_str }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's nothing in the [Curb documentation](http://rubydoc.info/gems/curb/file/README) regarding polling the filename. I don't know whether you have a particular aversion to parsing, but it's a simple process if using the [`URI` module](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html):

```
require 'uri'
url = 'http://google.com/robots.txt'
uri = URI.parse(url)
puts File.basename(uri.path)
#=> "robots.txt"
```

**UPDATE**:

In the comments to this question, the OP suggests using [`split()`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-split) to split the URL by slashes (`/`). While this may work in the majority of situations, it isn't a catch-all solution. For instance, *versioned files* won't be parsed correctly:

```
url = 'http://google.com/robots.txt?1234567890'
puts url.split('/').last
#=> "robots.txt?1234567890"
```

In comparison, using [URI.parse()](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html#method-c-parse) guarantees the filename – and *only* the filename – is returned:

```
require 'uri'
url = 'http://google.com/robots.txt?1234567890'
uri = URI.parse(url)
puts File.basename(uri.path)
#=> "robots.txt"
```

In sum, for optimal coherence and integrity, it's wise to use the `URI` library to parse universal resources – it's what it was created for, after all.

Comment: May be its better to extract the path like this `url.split("/").last`. But, asked since assumed I am just missing something very obvious, seeing the volume of options available for Curb.

Comment: @JikkuJose – Unfortunately, Curb unexpectedly doesn't provide such functionality. However, as for using `split()`, I've updated my answer with an explanation for why it __shouldn't__ be considered a catch-all solution. If this answer satisfies your question, would you kindly consider [accepting it as correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)?

Comment: Sure! Your answer is certainly more generic and will help most who might stumble on this.